# TypeError: str() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, class, typeerror

I have a problem with this code and I can't solve it !
Please excuse me, I'm a newbiee..

my code :

```
class Case: 
'''
 '''

def __init__ (self):
    '''
    '''

    self.__valeur = 0
    self.__cache = True

def str(self):
    '''
    '''

    if self.__cache == True :
        return '-'
    if self.__valeur == -1 :
        return '*'
    if self.__valeur == 0 :
        return ' '
    else :
        return self.__valeur
```

The error :

```
    >>> demineur.Case.str()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: str() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str()` is an instance method of your `Case` class. You have 2 options to call it:

```
>>> instance = Case()
>>> instance.str()
```

or

```
>>> instance = Case()
>>> Case.str(instance)
```

And as the error says, you are not passing an instance of `Case` to the `str` method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not name your methods or variables after the in-built reserved types like `str` `list` and `int`

you're probably trying to call the method like a static method, create an instance of your class and call it

```
Case.str() # Wrong because you're not passing an instance to it

mycase = Case() 
mycase.str() # my case automatically gets passed here implicity i.e mycase.str(mycase)
```